# Parsing XML and creating objects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

So I have the following String:

```
     "<Object>   
        <attribute1>a1</attribute1>   
        <attribute2>a2</attribute2>   
        <attribute3>a3</attribute3> 
     </Object>"
```

I want to use that to initialize my Object with the three attributes.
Any suggestions?
Does the Objective-c parser take in a string of xml?
Thanks

Comment: What's the source of your XML?

Comment: I am reading it from a soap response and extracting the xml from the object node into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `NSString` into data:

```
NSData *data = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And then you can feed it to `NSXMLParser`:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a plethora of XML-libraries for Objective-C, such as TBXML, libxml2, TouchXML, GDataXML, and many more. Chose the one that matches your taste of API. Personally, I recommend TBXML.